# Compile error in event handler subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, event-handling

I have a script that is supposed to run when a change is made in a particular sheet, so I created a Worksheet_Change() type sub in the specified sheet.

However, once a change is made, VBA spits out a Compile Error for "*Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment*", and highlights the first line of the sub, which is `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim newVal As String
Dim oldVal As String
Dim pageEnd As Integer
Dim oldRng As Range
Dim newRng As Range
Dim toolList As Range
```

The code continues on for many lines after the Dim statements.

How can I get past the first line?

Comment: Sometimes event procedure signatures get corrupted internally, even while able to "display" correctly. This even happened in classic VB. Copy the entire procedure to a text editor, like Notepad. Delete the entire procedure from the sheet module. Save the workbook. Use the VBE to insert the Worksheet_Change signature... let it do it. Copy the internal text from Notepad and paste it inside the signature the VBE created.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to help. I'm not entirely sure what happened, but it seems to have worked itself out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes event procedure signatures get corrupted internally, even while able to "display" correctly. This even happened in classic VB.

Copy the entire procedure to a text editor, like Notepad. Delete the entire procedure from the sheet module.

Save the workbook. Use the VBE to insert the Worksheet_Change signature... let it do it.

Copy the internal text from Notepad and paste it inside the signature the VBE created.